# Method declaration in jsp

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, methods

In this code, Im trying to access images and content that i have placed in the database, using jsp.

We have several conditions that it has to check and then proceed.

So we decided to place some of them in methods and then execute a for loop.

Therefore,we have declared methods in jsp,where il be placing the code.

Hence, I would like to know if the declaration is correct, because we are getting errors in the while loop and also some of the braces.

Could someone check and get back.

```
<%!
public void mfunction(String bname, String scname)
{
if(num_rows_brand==0 && num_rows_sc==0)
{
      ...}          
 else if(num_rows_brand>0 && num_rows_sc==0)
    {....
    while(rs_sh.next())
    { ...

    %>
         <h4>..</h4>
     <%         
     }  
   } 
  else if(num_rows_brand==0 && num_rows_sc>0)
   {
    que_sc=.....
    rs_b=st.executeQuery(que_sc);

    que_sh=......
    .....

    while(rs_sh.next())
    { 
        ...
    %>               ....

      <%         
     }  
  }

else if(num_rows_brand>0 && num_rows_sc>0)
{
    que3=.....
    rs3=st.executeQuery(que3);
    .....
    que4=.....
    rs4=st.executeQuery(que4);
    .....
   que_sh=.....
   .....

  while(rs_sh.next())
  { %>
    ...
  <%
}  
}
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't write Java code in JSP, JSP are meant for presentation. Second, It will be more helpful if you post a full code and point out what type of exception occurred. Which while loop is throwing error? Is the sql statement executed properly? Are you passing the right parameter and so on.......

Comment: the sql statement has executed properly..it points out error in the closing braces..is the flow correct? sorry the code is too long..couldn't post it

Comment: Remove block by block in order to decide which block causes the problem.